# How do I calculate these values from the given P.D.F?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

I can not figure out how to find $P(1.9\leq|X|)$ when $1.9$ is not given as any value of $x$. I did what I knew how to do, but I am not sure how to proceed from here. I have inserted my LaTex code below. The output can be seen [image: here]
 Consider a random variable $X$ whose probability mass function is given by

$$p(x)=\begin{cases}p&\text{if $x=-3$}\\
0.1&\text{if $x=-0.1$}\\
0.3&\text{if $x=2p$}\\
p&\text{if $x=3$}\\
p^2&\text{if $x=4$}\\
0&\text{if otherwise}\\
\end{cases} $$

What is $p$?

We know that the total probability must add up to 1.

Thus we get the following:$p^2+2p+0.4=1\Rightarrow p^2+2p-0.6\Rightarrow p=0.264911$

Thus the probability mass function is actually as follows:

$$p(x)=
    \begin{cases}
    0.264911&\text{if $x=-3$}\\
    0.1&\text{if $x=-0.1$}\\
    0.3&\text{if $x=0.529822$}\\
    0.264911&\text{if $x=3$}\\
    0.070178&\text{if $x=4$}\\
    0&\text{if otherwise}\\
    \end{cases}
    $$

Now we can make the following C.D.F:

$$\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}\hline x& -3    & -0.1  & 0.53  &     & 4 \\ \hline P(X\leq x) & 0.265 & 0.365 & 0.665 & 0.93 & 1 \\ \hline \end{array}$$

Compute $P(1.9\leq|X|\leq 3)$

First we will calculate $P(|X|\leq 3)$

$ P(|X|\leq 3)=0.264911+0.3+0.1+0.264911  = 0.93$

> What is $P(2x-3\leq4|X\geq 2.0)$
>
> Compute $Var(X)$
>
> Compute $E\left(F\left(p\right)\left(X\right)\right)$

Comment: Hint: $P(1.9 \leq |X|\leq 3)=P(-3 \leq X\leq -1.9)+P(1.9\leq X \leq 3)$ This is equal to $P(X\leq -1.9)-P(X<-3)+P(X\leq 3)-P(X<1.9)$ I´ve made an edit in order to adjust you code to MSE.

Comment: How did you adjust the code? I can never get my MSE to compile even if they work in LaTex. Also, can you help me with the variance question>

Comment: You have to click on the "edit" or the "edited ... mins ago" button to see the code.  The variance is just $$Var(X)=\mathbb E(X^2)-[\mathbb E(X)]^2=\sum x^2\cdot p(x)- \left(\sum x\cdot p(x) \right)^2$$, where $x \in \{-3, -0.1, 0.53, 3,4 \}$

Comment: @callculus I did that formula for variance and got a negative variance. But that can not be correct, right? Do you see any mistakes that I made? $$Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2=\sum x^2\cdot p(x)-\left(\sum x\cdot p(x)\right)^2= (0.265^2\cdot -3 + 0.1^2\cdot -0.1 + 0.3^2\cdot 0.53 + 0.265^2\cdot 3 + 0.07^2\cdot 4)-(0.265\cdot -3 + 0.1\cdot -0.1 + 0.3\cdot 0.53 + 0.265\cdot 3 + 0.07\cdot 4)^2=0.0663-(0.429)^2=0.0663-0.184=-0.1177$$

Comment: It´s the other way round. You have to square x= -3,-0.1,.., at $\mathbb E(X^2)$ and **not** $p(x)$ And yes the variance is always larger than $0$.

Comment: @callculus Thank you. That makes sense. Now I got the following: $$Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2=\sum x^2\cdot p(x)-\left(\sum x\cdot p(x)\right)^2= (0.265\cdot (-3)^2 + 0.1\cdot (-0.1)^2 + 0.3\cdot (0.53)^2 + 0.265\cdot (3)^2 + 0.07\cdot (4)^2)-(0.265\cdot -3 + 0.1\cdot -0.1 + 0.3\cdot 0.53 + 0.265\cdot 3 + 0.07\cdot 4)^2=5.975-(0.429)^2=5.975-0.184=5.79$$ But isn't that Variance too high?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83460/discussion-between-mohammed-shahid-and-callculus).

Comment: Why do you accept an answer although you have further questions? It seems that I have to do all the work for farruhota: Editing the question, answer further questions, ...

Comment: I have the same result. On the first view I dont´t see any mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1:
$$|X|\le 3 \iff -3\le X\le 3;\\
1.9\le |X| \iff X\le -1.9 \ \ \text{OR} \ \ X\ge 1.9.$$
Hint 2:
$$P(1.9\le |X|\le 3)=P(1.9\le |X|)+P(|X|\le 3)-1.$$
Hint 3:
$$P(2x-3\leq4|X\geq 2.0)=P(X\le 3.5|X\geq 2.0)=\frac{P(2.0\le X\le 3.5)}{P(X\ge 2.0)}.$$

Comment: Thank you. Those hints helped a lot. Can you also help with the variance question?